# Como saber a posição atual do usuário no ranking

Tags: mysql

Tenho a tabela **quiz_geral** e a tabela **conta**, a tabela **quiz_geral** é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo um sistema de ranking, ele usa várias linhas para fazer a soma de pontos de cada usuário, não apenas uma linha só (por várias complexidades que não cabe ser explicado). O sistema tem mais de 3000 usuários. O site vai mostrar a posição das 5 primeiras pessoas, assim:

```
SELECT conta.nome, conta.area, conta.departamento,
SUM(quiz_geral.ponto) AS pontosTotais
FROM quiz_geral
INNER JOIN conta ON quiz_geral.idconta = conta.id
GROUP BY quiz_geral.idconta
ORDER BY pontosTotais DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Funciona certinho. E também preciso mostrar a posição do ranking do usuário que está logado no sistema (ele pode ser o 4º ou o 775º, qualquer posição).

Como são mais de 3000 usuários, seria muito ruim percorrer toda a tabela para saber a posição apenas do usuário logado em si. Como contornar isso? Existe alguma forma de fazer um select para isso?

Criei um SQL Fiddle para entenderem melhor: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65f0/2 No exemplo eu queria tentar listar a posição do usuário Camila, que é 2, sem ter que passar por todas as linhas

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54634/discussion-on-question-by-caiocafardo-como-saber-a-posicao-atual-do-usuario-no-r)